# alternative to applocker windows 7 professional

Tags: windows, user-controls, windows-7-x64

Does any one know of a alternative version of applocker? I am running windows 7pro and i would like to Control Policies for each user on our PC.

The only thing i really need it to do is block installs of anything with out administrator permissions via username and password. I would like to also block access to certain areas of the computer for example i would like to block the user from being able to access the control panel.

I dont really want to spend a ton of money on this i have about 200 computers i need to do this to.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

"alternative version of applocker."  Here is a tutorial whichc gives you a white list, a freebie applocker.

<http://www.howtogeek.com/195381/ensure-a-windows-pc-never-gets-malware-by-whitelisting-applications/>

Best!  Robb Thurston.  Forward FOSS and Freeware!